# Virtual column email

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

How do I get a proper field builded with the data of all names columns + the @sales.es?

The following just set all to 0.

```
ALTER TABLE comercial ADD COLUMN email VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (nombre+'.'+ surname1 + surname2 +'@sales.es') VIRTUAL AFTER province;
```

Comment: Are any of those values `NULL`? SQL requires _all_ values to be non-`NULL` for concatenation to succeed, so you may need need to wrap everything in `COALESCE`.

Comment: Not a single null

Comment: What if you use explicit `CONCAT( nombre, '.,  surname1, surname2, '@sales.es' )` instead of `+` ?

Comment: Umm, syntax error...

Comment: Done, It works if I surround the concat like: ( CONCAT ( )), thank you.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB uses `CONCAT` for string concatenation, not `+`.

So change your statement to this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE comercial
    ADD COLUMN email VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CONCAT( nombre, '.,  surname1, surname2, '@sales.es' ) ) VIRTUAL AFTER province;
```